# Как скачать репозиторий Github с помощью request python

Tags: python, github, request

у меня появилась проблема...
Мне надо скачивать весь репозиторий в формате zip (сам гитхаб даёт мне эту ссылку [https://github.com/{user}/{repository_name}/archive/refs/heads/main.zip](https://github.com/%7Buser%7D/%7Brepository_name%7D/archive/refs/heads/main.zip))
Но при попытке получить контент по этой ссылке при помощи `request.get` python меня откровенно посылает. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests

Comment: а во ответ Not Found

Comment: Все работает. Добавьте опцию `allow_redirects=True` в `requests.get(url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True)`

Comment: Спасибо всем большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github использует редиректы при скачивании файла. Это надо учитывать при запросе файла с помощью опции `allow_redirects=True`

```
import requests

def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    with requests.get(url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
                f.write(chunk)
    return local_filename

filename = download_file('https://github.com/ndrwpvlv/pyyadisk/archive/refs/heads/main.zip')
print(filename)
```

Код скачивания взял отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Не за что) Welcome)